# how to listen to contacts changes in phonebook when app is terminated(Oreo)

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

I want to sync new contact and changes to contacts in Phonebook with my app....whether its open or terminated like whatsapp do. Tried with sync adapter but facing issues as dirty flag not changing on update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ContentObserver`

Refer to this  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver)

Use service to run in background for watching contact change

```
public class ContactWatchService extends Service {
private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            //Register contact observer
            startContactObserver();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
private void startContactObserver(){
    try{
        //Registering contact observer
        getApplication().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,new ContObserver(new Handler(),getApplicationContext()));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
    // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
    // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
    // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments");
    thread.start();

    // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
    // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // We don't provide binding, so return null
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try{
        //Code below is commented.
        //Turn it on if you want to run your service even after your app is closed
        /*Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactWatchService.class);
        startService(intent);*/
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

Register this as service in manifest

```
 <service
        android:name=".service.syncAdapter.ContactWatchService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

ContactObserver

```
public class ContObserver extends ContentObserver {

Context context;


@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);

   contactAdded(selfChange);
}

public void contactAdded(boolean selfChange) {
    if (!selfChange) {
        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
                Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    //moving cursor to last position
                    //to get last element added
                    cursor.moveToLast();
                    String contactName = null, photo = null, contactNumber = null;
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                        if (pCur != null) {
                            pCur.moveToFirst();
                            contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            contactName = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                           //here you will get your contact information


                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Do not forget to add this in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

finally start service

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ContactWatchService.class));
```

Comment: this will work only when the app is active or in background.....what to do when app is terminated??....and how to detect edited contacts through this??

Comment: dude this will work when app is terminated you can see that the ContactWatch service is `START_STICKY` just give it a try i am suing this and is working fine with me

Comment: Thanks..but background services don't work in oreo....have u tested it in oreo?? and how can we detect changes in contacts by this methods

Comment: use firebase Job dispatcher for that

Comment: How can we schedule event based jobs with dispatcher...can u please share some code for this

Comment: you can take some help from here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: i have tested job dispatcher in oreo and is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful, I do not test this personally. in `onCreate` method of your activity add this code :

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, new ContentObserver() {
            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                super.onChange(selfChange);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
            }
        });
```

In `onChange` method you will notified by the changes.

Comment: this will pnly work when the app is active or background not when terminated.

Comment: @Prashant : so you should use background service to do this job for you.

Comment: background services are killed in oreo

Comment: @Prashant : Pleas read this link : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: how can we use contacts content provider with job scheduler....have you seen any example??